# Recursive Sum Array In Value Angular5 Typescript

Tags: php, database, angular, typescript, angular5

I'm developing angular5 app now using typescript as scriptiong language. I have a problem to recursive sum array in typescript array.

Let says I have PurchaseClass and DepositClass
In my PurchaseClass its contain

```
{[id:1,amount:133],[id:2,amount:40]}
```

In my DepositClass contain array like this

```
{[deposit_id:6,deposit_amount:50],[deposit_id:7,deposit_amount:100]}
```

In my usedDepositClass is empty array to allocate the deposit
what I want to achieve in my usedDepositClass contain

```
{[deposit_id:6,id:1,deposit_used:50,amount_left:83],[deposit_id:7,id:1,deposit_used:83,amount_left:0],[deposit_id:7,id:1,deposit_used:17,amount_left:23],}
```

I've tried many ways like iterating the purchaseClass first and nested the depositClass inside but its alway generate wrong result.
Please,someone provide the code to achieve it

Comment: Your question needs some formatting

Comment: Sorry...what kind of formatting

Comment: To make your question readable